# Regular expression to allow punctuation marks and spaces between words

Tags: javascript, regex, alphanumeric, punctuation

I want a regular expression that prevents white spaces and only allows letters and numbers with punctuation marks(Spanish). The regex below works great, but it doesn't allow punctuation marks.

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+( [a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*$
```

For example, when using this regular expression "Hola como estas" is fine, but "Hola, como estás?" does not match.

How can I tweak it to punctuation marks?

Answer (score 3):

Use `\W+` instead of space and add `\W*` at the end:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+(?:\W+[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*\W*$/
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/F39VCH/1)

**EXPLANATION**

```
                         EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [a-zA-Z0-9_]+            any character of: 'a' to 'z', 'A' to 'Z',
                           '0' to '9', '_' (1 or more times (matching
                           the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \W+                      non-word characters (all but a-z, A-Z, 0-
                             9, _) (1 or more times (matching the
                             most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [a-zA-Z0-9_]+            any character of: 'a' to 'z', 'A' to
                             'Z', '0' to '9', '_' (1 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )*                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \W*                      non-word characters (all but a-z, A-Z, 0-
                           9, _) (0 or more times (matching the most
                           amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I just tested the pattern in angular validators and it's like it doesn't read the whole pattern and ends up doing the validation wrong. What do you recommend me to do in this case? @Ryszard

Comment: @JoseAguirre Please add the code you use into the question to see where it might go wrong.

Comment: @JoseAguirre Make sure you do not wrap the `/^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+(?:\W+[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*\W*$/` with any quotation marks.

Comment: Thanks, the error was due to the quotes since I added the pattern to a property within the component so as not to be repeating the pattern over and over again. But adding the pattern directly in the Validators.pattern() works fine. @Ryszard